# How to support commandline syntax "-DEVICE:iphone" in Boost::Program_Options?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

The default syntax for Boost::Program_Options is "--DEVICE iphone". How can I support syntax "-DEVICE:iphone" or "-DEVICE=iphone"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boost.Program_Options has a pretty large number of [option styles](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/command_line_style/style_t.html). The particular combination you seem to be going for would be:

```
command_line_style::long_allow_adjacent |
command_line_style::short_allow_adjacent |
command_line_style::allow_long_disguise
```

These options should be given to the `style` function of your command line parser:

```
    po::store(po::command_line_parser(argc, argv).style(<your styles here>).run(), vm);
```

Comment: This would not handle ':' as option/value separator though. For that, one would need a custom parser, which is the first item in the "Howto" section of the documentation.