# Boost Program Options Syntax

Tags: c++, boost, command-line, boost-program-options

I'm using [boost::program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/program_options.html) to read the users' input from the command line argument. It works very nicely and allows me to output helpful usage messages and validate input properly. However, by default long option names must come after a double-dash for example `--my_long_option` and short options come after a single dash *and* must be a single character, example; `-m`.

Is there a way to either...

- Allow long options after a single `-`?
- Allow short options to have more than one character?

Thus allowing me to have command lines which looks like

```
./a.out -myopt1 foo -myopt2 bar
```

The two possibilities should have the same effect though from a programming point of view the first would be better. I had a look at [boost::program_options::command_line_style](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/command_line_style/style_t.html) but it doesn't look like it can do what I need.

Thanks

**Edit:** Further to accepted answer below to get it to use that style one must add the following code (following the naming convention of the boost docs)

```
po::store(
    po::command_line_parser(ac,av)
        .options(desc)
        .style(
            po::command_line_style::unix_style
          | po::command_line_style::allow_long_disguise)
        .run(),
    vm);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to support commandline syntax "-DEVICE:iphone" in Boost::Program_Options?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906991/how-to-support-commandline-syntax-deviceiphone-in-boostprogram-options)

Comment: Yes pretty much duplicate but the answer given there is not quite correct. It's not hard to work out what the solution is based on that but I've added it here for completeness.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Short options by definition have just one character. If they had more, they'd be long options.

To allow long options to start with a single dash, include the `allow_long_disguise` command-line style, [as described on the documentation page you linked to](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/command_line_style/style_t.html#boost.program_options.command_line_style.style_t.allow_long_disguise):

> It's possible to introduce long options by the same character as short options, see allow_long_disguise.

Comment: Oh dear, I swear that wasn't there when I looked. Not enough Coffee obviously. I'll try it out tomorrow when I get a chance. Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be the best solution, although there are a few caveats to be aware of.  An unknown argument "`-myopt1`" will trigger the exception message "`unknown option -m`". Also the autogenerated help text will still show "`--myopt2`".